# Trigonometry - word problem

Tags: trigonometry, word-problem

### **The Question**

The machine tool diagram shows a symmetric die punch.
In this view, the rounded tip is part of a circle of radius r, and the slanted
sides are tangent to that circle and form an angle of 54◦. The top and
bottom sides of the die punch are horizontal. Use the information in the
diagram to find the radius r.

### **The given diagram**

[image]

**My attempts to solve**

[image]

ABNM is a rectangle, therefore
$$AB = MN$$
$$AC = \frac {AB}{2} = ML$$
$$Θ = \frac {54°}{2} = 27°$$
In △LNK
$$ \tan27° = \frac{17/16}{h} $$
$$ h = \frac{17/16}{\tan27°} $$

$$w = h - 1\frac{1}{2}$$
$$\tan27° = \frac{x}{w}$$
$$x = w\tan27°$$

I don't think I've come any close to the solution, so I'll be grateful if you give me some hints or corrections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are closer than you think.

Drop a perpendicular from $O$ to $KN$. Since the circle is tangent to $KN$, we have:

$$\frac r{r+w} = \sin 27^\circ$$

or

$$r = \frac {w\sin 27^\circ}{1-\sin 27^\circ}$$

Comment: Thank you for the help.